# bootstrap span6 not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a script that closes and opens another div after every 3rd iteration. The script opens a div with a class of "span6".

As I am using bootstrap, the bootstrap should automatically align to span6 divs which are inside a span12 div, side by side. But it's not happening. They are coming beneath each other. In the window of inspect element all the markup is fine and no errors.

Why is that happening?

Code:

**JS:**

```
var a = '<div class="span6">';

var length = tag_array.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {


    a += '<div class="tag">' + toTitleCase(tag_array[i]) + '</div>';

    if (i % 3 == 2) {

        a += '</div><div class="span6">';
    }

}

a += '</div>';

document.write(a);
```

**HTML:(screenshot of the inpect element window)**
[image]

*The code is from the hovered line to the selected line.*

**Please help.**

Answer (score 2):

Your grid format is invalid, the `span*` elements should have the parent as a `row-fluid` element, in your case the `span6` element has `span12` as the parent.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pHf6y/2/

It should be

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">1</div>
            <div class="span6">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">1</div>
    <div class="span6">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui bootstrap version used

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sk7e6/1/ ... the row-fluid should have span elements as children.. so the `h4` should be moved out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38263/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in version 3.0.0 they are using .col-xs-[1-12] or .col-sm-[1-12] or .col-md-[1-12] or col-lg-[1-12].

Comment: what do they all mean?